# Temporary file for unix domain socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I create temporary file for unix domain socket.

```c
int fd;
char sf[] = {"/tmp/socket-XXXXXX"};

if ((fd = mkstemp(sf)) == -1)
    exit(SOCKFERR);
close(fd);
```

Buf when I assigns the address to the socket I need remove this file (`bind()` function works only if file which will socket file doesn't exist yet).

```c
int sfd;
struct sockaddr_un addr;

if ((sfd = socket(PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    exit(SOCKERR);  

unlink(sf);
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
snprintf(addr.sun_path, 108, sf);   /* 108 is length of add.sun_path */

if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0)
    exit(BINDERR);
```

How can I create temporary file for unix domain socket without removing it before `bind()`?

Comment: Because that's how `bind` works with local sockets? And remember that using a random name for a local socket is only useful if you use it inside the same process tree (the process and its children, in which case pipes could be used instead) or somehow present the name for other (unrelated) processes. Named pipes and local sockets are really only useful if their names are well-known.

Comment: A note about your code: It's not portable. The POSIX specification says that the size of `sun_path` varies between systems, and even the Linux manual page says that you shouldn't hardcode a specific length. Since it's an array, you should be using `sizeof addr.sun_path` to get its size.

Comment: Related: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_un.h.html

Comment: There's `socketpair()` if you want to use Unix domain sockets with related processes, like a child communicating with its parent.

Comment: Thanks guys, your comments are really helpful.

Comment: I use socket file in unrelated processes (not child and parent). Socket file creator `printf` file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create temporary file for unix domain socket without removing it before bind()?

It is not possible. Everything in linux is a file. "Socket" is a "socket file". With `mkstemp` you create what is called a "regular file" or a "normal file".

If you create a regular file and try to create a directory with the same path, you will get an error EEXISTS. You have to remote the file, then create a directory.

Exactly same happens when you try to create a socket file with the same name as existing regular file - the file already exists there. When you try to create a symbolic link or a hard link or a "character device" ("character special file") or any other file type. You have to remove the preexisting file, then create the other file type.

Comment: Thanks. It is pity, that bind can't overwrite existing file.

Comment: The common solution is to use `mkdtemp`